# Schedule task to be executed later (time + date) android

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, schedule

**I just search for code that let me do an action after the timer (with specific date and time) finish (in Kotlin) and save it in a list**

**Like timer for post a tweet on Twitter:**
https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-editing-and-optimization/scheduled-tweets.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics.html) for that.

**Dependency:**

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.0"
```

**Example:**

```
class LogWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        // Do the work here--in this case, upload the images.
        Log.i("ToastWorker", "doWork: Working ⚒ ⚒ ⚒")

        // Indicate whether the task finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

**Then set the delay time**

```
val logWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LogWorker>()
        .setInitialDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // here you can set the delay time in Minutes, Hours
        .build()
```

**Start the timer**

```
WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(toastWorkRequest)
```

Here is a [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/#0) for more insight. You can also [read more here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics.html)