# Run a method at a specific time without repeat

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, alarmmanager, handler

I need to call a web API at a specific time without repeat it. I use `AlarmManager` but it never fired. I also implement `handler.postDelayed` but it repeats itself. I don't know how to implement it correctly.

this is my alarmManager :

```
 alarmManager = (getCTX()?.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)) as (AlarmManager)

        var intent: Intent = Intent(getCTX(), NextLiveReceiver::class.java)


        intent.putExtra("next", next)
        intent.putExtra("curTime", curTime)

        myPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getCTX(),
                0,//next.toInt(),
                intent,
                0
            )

        var ALARM_TYPE = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(ALARM_TYPE, next, myPendingIntent);
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            alarmManager.setExact(ALARM_TYPE, next, myPendingIntent);
        else
            alarmManager.set(ALARM_TYPE, next, myPendingIntent)
```

this is AlarmManagerReceiver :

```
class NextLiveReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

            var next: Long = intent.getLongExtra("next", 0)
            var current: Long = intent.getLongExtra("curTime", 0)

            if (next > 0 && current > 0) {

                EventBus.send(NextEvent(true, next, current))
            }

    }
}
```

and this is my handler :

```
 var handler: Handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed({

            viewModel.fetchLiveInfo(viewModel.currentChannelId.value!!, next, 0)
        }, delay)

        handler.removeCallbacks(null)
```

Comment: hey check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887800/schedule-task-to-be-executed-later-time-date-android/59888122#59888122) and see if it helps

Comment: @Max I implement as you said but it didn't work as I expected. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorkManager, Handler, and AlarmManager did not work as I expected. So, I resolved it with **Kotlin delay** in this way :

```
  runBlocking {
                                scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main + handler) {
                                    Timber.i("--Launch-- start : ${getUnixTime()}")
                                    delay(delayTime)

                                    removeRate()
                                    refetchLiveInfo(channelId, liveInfoResult[0].next, 1)
                                    Timber.i("--Launch-- ended : ${getUnixTime()}")
                                }

                            }
```